# Angular Material (2) mdSelect: How to hide generated span.mat-select-underline tag

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, angular-material2

My design calls for the select form control to be displayed with no underline, but I'm struggling to accomplish this.

*Wireframe design:*

[image]

*Actual look atm*:

[image]

The directive generates this HTML output:

[image]

The SCSS I've written tries to target the *mat-select-underline* class, but it's not being applied once the directive generates the markup.

```
& md-select {
      padding-top: 0;

      .mat-select-trigger > .mat-select-underline {
        display: none;
      }
    }
```

I've also tried to use the directive's *panelClass* @Input property, but I'm not entirely sure where that's gets applied, since they're still working on supplementing their docs.

[image]

```
.mat-no-underline {
      span.mat-select-underline {
        display: none;
      }
    }

<!-- HTML -->
<md-select [(ngModel)]="commodityLine.classCode"
                           panelClass="mat-no-underline"
                           name="shipment_info_commodity_class_{{index}}"
                           placeholder="Class"
                           floatPlaceholder="never"
                           required="true"
                           aria-label="Commodity Class">

                  <md-option *ngFor="let classItem of commodityClassOptions"
                             value="classItem">
                    {{classItem}}
                  </md-option>
                </md-select>
```

mdSelect API docs: https://material.angular.io/components/select/api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in your component.

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  ...
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

And use this class in your component's css file:

```
md-select.mat-select-underline{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the solution I came up with as well, but I'm curious as to why we have to do this?

Comment: In order to override the default styles, we need to disable ViewEncapsulation. Please upvote as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Apply the following style

```
md-select .mat-select-underline{
  display:none;
}
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/qYHbwrxiuKr8q7Hn7Awu?p=preview)**

Comment: That works when I add it to my global styles, but not when it's in my component's scoped styles. I think it may have something to do with [Angular's view encapsulation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation)

Comment: try to use the component selector infront so it will be applied only to that component